# How to get the class of a rule in Juzzy (fuzzy logic library)?

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic

I've tried Juzzy in Java. After defining the membership functions, antecedents, consequences and my rule base, I tried to print the output of a sample input which I entered. I saw that the only output can be the defuzzication number (type of double). But I need the class of the rule which fires with a sample input, not the  defuzzication number. Anyone knows about the appropriate function for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
rulebase.evaluate(0).get(tip)
```